Pydantic-Settings: Environment Variables Prioritize Over Init Args with Aliases
I am using Pydantic v2 with BaseSettings (pydantic-settings) to load configurations from environment variables. However, I encountered an issue where environment variables seem to override the initialization arguments, even when I expect the init arguments to take priority.
Here’s a simplified version of my code:
from pydantic import Field, StrictStr
from pydantic_settings import BaseSettings, SettingsConfigDict

class MySettings(BaseSettings):
    api_key: StrictStr = Field(..., alias="TEST_API_KEY")
    aws_region: StrictStr = Field(..., alias="AWS_REGION")

    model_config = SettingsConfigDict(extra="ignore", populate_by_name=True)

# .env file
# TEST_API_KEY="TEST_API_KEY_VALUE"
# AWS_REGION="us-east-1"

print(MySettings().model_dump())
# Expected: {'api_key': 'TEST_API_KEY_VALUE', 'aws_region': 'us-east-1'}

print(MySettings(api_key="ANOTHER_API_KEY_TO_OVERRIDE").model_dump())
# Expected: {'api_key': 'ANOTHER_API_KEY_TO_OVERRIDE', 'aws_region': 'us-east-1'}
# Actual: {'api_key': 'TEST_API_KEY_VALUE', 'aws_region': 'us-east-1'}

print(MySettings(api_key=111).model_dump())
# Expected: ValidationError due to type mismatch
# Actual: {'api_key': 'TEST_API_KEY_VALUE', 'aws_region': 'us-east-1'}


I've also tried adjusting SettingsConfigDict and using a custom PydanticBaseSettingsSource, but the behavior persists. Debugging the Pydantic code base itself shows both the constructor and environment values present, but the latter is prioritized due to alias matching (maybe).
My question basically is How I can ensure that init arguments are prioritized over environment variables when using aliases in pydantic-settings?
Python 3.11.8 (arm64)
pydantic==2.7.1
pydantic-settings==2.2.1
pydantic_core==2.18.2

UPDATE:
I forgot to mention, but by updating the extra="allow":
print(MySettings().model_dump())
print(MySettings(api_key="ANOTHER_API_KEY_TO_OVERRIDE").model_dump())
print(MySettings(api_key=111).model_dump())

{'api_key': 'TEST_API_KEY_VALUE', 'aws_region': 'us-east-1'}
{'api_key': 'ANOTHER_API_KEY_TO_OVERRIDE', 'aws_region': 'us-east-1'}
{'api_key': 111, 'aws_region': 'us-east-1'}

As you can see, there will be no validation if I pass integer to api_key.

if you remove extra="ignore", the api_key= will cause an error despite populate_by_name=True being set.

@VPfB I've updated my question with extra="allow" and can confirm that by removing the extra it's not gonna work.  What I'm looking at here is how to override api_key by init vars instead of environment variables and why the validation is not working when I pass extra allow.

It works as expected with the alias names only. For instance MySettings(TEST_API_KEY=...) will take precedence over environemnt as expected. It seems to me the populate_by_name is somehow ignored. The name api_key is treated as an extra key. The result depends on the config. Maybe you have discovered a bug...

@VPfB Thanks for replying. Yeah, I was thinking about it too, but wanted to make sure that I'm not missing something. I'll post it to the Pydantic GitHub page and see how it goes.

Posted here: https://github.com/pydantic/pydantic-settings/issues/293
